# Excel: Cells being highlighted that shouldn't be

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a macro in excel that will sort and then highlights valid and invalid data based on the values in Column U. Valid data is yellow, invalid is red. It is a very simple macro but I seem to be having difficulty with one line of code.

```
If Range("U" & i).Value > "225" And Range("U" & i).Value < "305" Then Range("P" & i, "U" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 50, 0)
```

For some reason this highlights cells with the value "3" in them as well. I've gone over this numerous times and feel stupid, I've commented and uncommented everything and this definitely is the line of code causing the issue. It works perfectly besides 3, just 3. 0,1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9 and others don't get highlighted as invalid. Is this an issue with my code or excel?

[Relevant portion of worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpQSX.png)

I made a workaround where after I highlight errors I highlight all cells with the 3 as valid, I would just like to figure out what the issue was with my original code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the quotes off the numbers.

```
If Range("U" & i).Value > 225 And Range("U" & i).Value < 305 Then Range("P" & i, "U" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 50, 0)
```

Comment: Thank you, what do the quotes change about a number exactly? In most code I've seen there have been quotes around values for cells, numerical values included.

Comment: It changes a number to a string, so 3 is in between 225 and 305. Numerical Values will normally not have quotes.